# Cannot read property 'FacebookAuthProvider' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, facebook-login, angularfire2

I'm trying to use angular firebase and connect with facebook, but im got this error:

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FacebookAuthProvider' of undefined
at AuthService.signInWithFacebook (auth.service.ts:26)
at AppComponent.signInWithFacebook (app.component.ts:20)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:2)
at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
at eval (core.js:10629)
at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.js:2628)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
```

I tried to change firebase version and change the dependencies and so far nothing work.

dependencies:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "4.13.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.1.10"
```

auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private userDetails: firebase.User = null;
constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { 
      this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
this.user.subscribe(
        (user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.userDetails = user;
            console.log(this.userDetails);
          }
          else {
            this.userDetails = null;
          }
        }
      );
  }
signInWithFacebook() {
    return this._firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(
      new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
    )
  }
```

what im doing worng?
thanks

Comment: Does the same error occur with the latest stable version on AngularFire2? Seems likely to be an RC bug. Where is the code in auth.service.ts that is calling new FacebookAuthProvider? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an @ in the import.

```
import { firebase } from `@firebase/app'
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was changing the import statement in my `home.ts`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

Comment: Answers need to be in English https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange . I tried translating your answer to English. Bear in mind that there is also a Spanish language Stack Overflow https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: What if they are interested because they do not translate? luck

Comment: That's the problem, I think the decision to always use English in this Stack Overflow is that other users must be able to read your answer. If suddenly questions are in Chinese, answers in Spanish and comments in Russian noone will understand it and the quality might drop or people might leave. Suerte;) or rather, best regards!